# React input losing state after typing in modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I've got a modal where a user needs to fill in his email adres. The problem is that the input field is losing state after every typed letter.

**Parent component:**

```
const { show: openExampleMailingModal, ExampleMailingModal } = useExampleMailingHook(mailable);

<ExampleMailingModal />
```

**ExampleMailingModal:**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Modal from '@/crm/Shared/Modals/Modal';
import TextInput from '@/crm/Shared/TextInput';

export const useExampleMailingHook = (mailable) => {
    const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false);
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');

    const show = () => setIsVisible(true);
    const hide = () => setIsVisible(false);

    const ExampleMailingModal = () => (
        <>
            {isVisible && (
                <Modal close={hide}>
                    <>
                        <TextInput
                            key="test123"
                            name="email"
                            placeholder="Email"
                            value={email}
                            onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                        />
                    </>
                </Modal>
            )}
        </>
    );

    return {
        show,
        hide,
        ExampleMailingModal,
    };
};
```

**TextInput:**

```
import React from 'react';

export default ({ label, name, className, type = 'text', errors = [], ...props }) => {
    return (
        <div className={className}>
            {label && (
                <label htmlFor={name} className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
                    {label}
                </label>
            )}
            <input
                id={name}
                name={name}
                type={type}
                {...props}
                className={`mt-1 block w-full border border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm py-2 px-3 focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 sm:text-sm ${
                    errors.length ? 'border-red-500' : ''
                }`}
            />
            {errors && <div className="text-red-500 text-sm mt-1">{errors}</div>}
        </div>
    );
};
```

I'm using the input field in several other places where it's working. But in my modal it doesn't. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

You are declaring a new `ExampleMailingModal` each render cycle, so the old one is unmounted and a new instance mounted. This is why focus is lost after each rerender.

## Solution

Move the `ExampleMailingModal` component ***outside*** the hook so it's not redeclared and return the JSX.

```
const ExampleMailingModal = ({ isVisible, hide, ...inputProps }) =>
  isVisible ? (
    <Modal close={hide}>
      <TextInput
        key="test123"
        name="email"
        placeholder="Email"
        {...inputProps}
      />
    </Modal>
  ) : null;

const useExampleMailingHook = (mailable) => {
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false);
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");

  const show = () => setIsVisible(true);
  const hide = () => setIsVisible(false);

  return {
    show,
    hide,
    ExampleMailingModal: (
      <ExampleMailingModal
        isVisible={isVisible}
        hide={hide}
        value={email}
        onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
      />
    )
  };
};
```

Usage:

```
const { show, hide, ExampleMailingModal } = useExampleMailingHook();

...

{ExampleMailingModal}
```

[image: Edit react-input-losing-state-after-typing-in-modal]